# SimpleAuth pod not installing properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I use several pods in my Xcode project, all work perfectly well except [SimpleAuth](http://simpleauth.io)

Here is my code in my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 2.3'
pod 'SAMCache'

source 'https://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth'
use_frameworks!
pod 'SimpleAuth/Instagram'
```

Then, I install my pod using my terminal targeting my project folder.  And as you can see, the "SimpleAuth" folder created in my project is empty when it should include all the objective-c classes that it needs to operate:

[image]

Any help by more experience objective-c coders much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you using two ways. instead use simple

## podflie

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 2.3'
pod 'SAMCache'
pod 'SimpleAuth/Instagram'
```

there is no need of mentioning source path. Cocoapods will do it automatically.
It is not used because if sometime in future if it change then you will have a problem.